# PrintWriter doesn't support \n?

Tags: java

I need to have a single String that holds a multi-line message that will print to the console and also to a .txt file. However, PrintWriter obviously doesn't support \n, as it outputs on one line. Is there another way to print on a new line rather than println multiple times?

***Edit:***

Code looks something along the lines of this:

```
PrintWriter outputFile = new PrintWriter("StatFile.txt");
outputFile.println("Number of scores: 8" + "\n" + "Minimum score: 55");
```

But the text file looks like this:

```
Number of scores: 8Minimum score: 55
```

Comment: ...yes. That's the issue.

Comment: Then show us your code, tell us how to reproduce your error, and show us the error output and where it's going wrong.

Comment: PrintWriter supports \n

Comment: `\n` is the LF character (you might need `\r\n` if you're on Windows). You can get the correct line separator for your system from `System.lineSeparator()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Summarising the comments of others. `PrintWriter` does support `\n`, so perhaps try:

```
outputFile.println("Number of scores: 8" + System.lineSeparator() + "Minimum score: 55");
```